# Load correct audio decoder for Mac

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

As far as I have researched, Apple is loading an audio decoder based on a file extension.

I have an .m4a file which I have manually renamed to .aac extension. After that, the decoder fails to decode it, but the apple native audio player plays it!

```
ExtAudioFileRef audioFile;
ExtAudioFileOpenURL(url, &audioFile);
```

Calling this function ends up with an error.

How can I handle this situation using the Core Audio framework? Do I have to somehow configure a custom decoder? If yes, then how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you renaming m4a to aac? what are you trying to decode the m4a file to? LPCM?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman, suppose some bad guy has renamed it! :D I want to make sure my code handles this case :) Yes I want to convert it into LPCM.